# Xamarin forms android Certificate pinning network_security_config how do you test it?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am implementing certificate pinning via network_security_config and I have something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
<domain-config>
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">example.com</domain>
    <pin-set expiration="2018-01-01">
        <pin digest="SHA-256">7HIpactkIAq2Y49orFOOQKurWxmmSFZhBCoQYcRhJ3Y=</pin>
        <!-- backup pin -->
        <pin digest="SHA-256">fwza0LRMXouZHRC8Ei+4PyuldPDcf3UKgO/04cDM1oE=</pin>
    </pin-set>
</domain-config>
```

Now how do I actually test it works?

I could not find anything out there on how you prove that works eg "Invalid certificate error" and I can close the app or do something else...

thanks for any suggestions, any sample out there using forms

Comment: Please check the Microsoft blog below, it would be helpful. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/cleartext-http-android-network-security/

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT thanks for your reply  I did already read that blog but offer no advice on how to test the implemenation

Comment: Check the code in the link below to use `IX509TrustManager ` to check: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/14938/certificate-pinning-in-monodroid

Answer (score 0):

> I am implementing certificate pinning via network_security_config and I have something like
>
> ```xml
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <network-security-config>
> <domain-config>
>    <domain includeSubdomains="true">example.com</domain>
>    <pin-set expiration="2018-01-01">
>        <pin digest="SHA-256">7HIpactkIAq2Y49orFOOQKurWxmmSFZhBCoQYcRhJ3Y=</pin>
>        <!-- backup pin -->
>        <pin digest="SHA-256">fwza0LRMXouZHRC8Ei+4PyuldPDcf3UKgO/04cDM1oE=</pin>
>    </pin-set>
> </domain-config>
> ```
>
> Now how do I actually test it works?

The test to confirm if pinning is working while using the network security config file is independent of the network stack being used and from the framework used to build your mobile app.

To test it works you just need to change a digit in the base64 encoded pin, the SHA-256 digest. So, if you change `7HIpactkIAq2Y49orFOOQKurWxmmSFZhBCoQYcRhJ3Y=` to `0HIpactkIAq2Y49orFOOQKurWxmmSFZhBCoQYcRhJ3Y=` then the app should fail with a pinning error.

If you still have doubts just follow the [Pin Test App](https://github.com/approov/example-android-static-certificate-pinning#testing-the-app-doesnt-work-on-certificate-pinning-mismatch) demo:

> ##### Testing the App Doesn't Work on Certificate Pinning Mismatch
>
> Edit the ./main/res/xml/network_security_config.xml file and change one or more digits in the pin digest in order to simulate a certificate pinning failure.
>
> A certificate pinning failure occurs usually due to a MitM attack, due to a change in the TLS certificates of the API backend or due to a firewall (usually used in corporate environments) on the network used by the mobile app.
>
> The certificate pinning failure will occur when the mobile app tries to make an API request and during the TLS handshake is not able to match the pin in the network security config file with the pin extracted from the certificate presented by the API backend.

The Pin Test App is an step by step example for using the free online [Mobile Certificate Pinning Generator](https://approov.io/tools/static-pinning) to extract the public key pin and generate the correct `network_security_config.xml` file for all the domains you want to implement certificate pinning for on your mobile app.